ReCaptcha string(75) "{ "success": false, "error-codes": [ "invalid-input-response" ] }" [closed]
Al hacer submit en mi formulario me devuelve string(75) "{ "success": false, "error-codes": [ "invalid-input-response" ] }". No sé lo que hacer las claves están bien, creo que el problema es del backend pero tampoco descarto que haya hecho algo mal en el frontend. Aquí dejo el backend:
  $token = $_POST['token'];



include ('keys.php');
  $url = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify';
  $r = "{$url}?secret={$keys['secret']}&response={$token}"; // response

  $fr = file_get_contents($r); // final response
  var_dump($fr);

  if ($fr === false) {
    $errors .= "Captcha verification failed. Please try again later.";
}
  $json = json_decode($fr, true);
  $frr = $json['success']; // final response result

  if($frr === false){
    $errors .= "Captcha error. Reload the page.";
  }

  if($json['score'] < 0.7){
      $errors .= "Captcha detect that you are a robot";
  }

Agradeceria una respuesta sobre como solucionarlo. Gracias por adelantado.

El $token si te está obteniendo el valor correcto que le estás pasando? , comprueba que sea correcto.
